# Water vapor proof wrap?

Tags: waterproofing

I need a completely waterproof wrap because I am installing some materials that are very sensitive to moisture and need to be completely dry.

Tyvek, for example, is breathable, so it cannot be used since it will let water vapor through (I assume).

Is there a wrap that is totally water proof?

Comment: How much time do you want to spend getting to it afterwards?

Comment: Homebuilding grade would be something like polyethylene film.  But the big benefit of Tyvek-like barriers is letting the vapor and humidity out on the warm side of the partition so it doesn't condense into liquid on the cold side.

Comment: What are you wrapping? Is this a box , a room we need more information.